# Trying to filter in dask.read_parquet tries to compare NoneType and str

Tags: python, dask, parquet

I have a project where I pass the following `load_args` to `read_parquet`:

```
filters = {'filters': [('itemId', '=', '9403cfde-7fe5-4c9c-916c-41ff0b595c5c')]}
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.read_parquet.html), a `List[Tuple]` like this should be accepted and I should get all partitions which match the predicate (or equivalently, filter out those that do not).

However, it gives me the following error:

```
│                                                                                  │
│ /home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/parquet/  |
| core.py:1275 in apply_conjunction                                                │
|                                                                                  |
|   1264 |   for part, stats in zip(parts, statistics):                            |
|   1265 |   |   |   |   if "filter" in stats and stats["filter"]:                 |
|   1266 |   |   |   |   |  continue  # Filtered by engine                         |
|   1267 |   |   |   |   try:                                                      |
|   1268 |   |   |   |   |  c = toolz.groupby("name", stats["columns"])[column][0] |
|   1269 |   |   |   |   |  min = c["min"]                                         |
|   1270 |   |   |   |   |  max = c["max"]                                         |
|   1271 |   |   |   |   except KeyError:                                          |
│   1272 │   │   │   │   │   out_parts.append(part)                                │
│   1273 │   │   │   │   │   out_statistics.append(stats)                          │
│   1274 │   │   │   │   else:                                                     │
│ ❱ 1275 │   │   │   │   │   if (                                                  │
│   1276 │   │   │   │   │   │   operator in ("==", "=")                           │
│   1277 │   │   │   │   │   │   and min <= value <= max                           │
│   1278 │   │   │   │   │   │   or operator == "!="                               │
╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

It seems that `read_parquet` tries to compute `min` and `max` values for my `str` value that I wish to filter on, but I'm not sure that makes sense in this case. Even so, `str` values should be comparable (though it might not make a huge amount of sense in this case, seeing how the `itemId` is a random UUID).

Still, I expected this to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have the same issue, I did check the existence of `min` and `max` statistics w/ `pyarrow.parquet.ParquetFile(<file>).metadata.row_group(0).column(<i>).statistics.<min|max>` so I am sure that it exists. Nonetheless, dask is still giving me this None comparison error...

Comment: In my case, I was trying to load partitioned data from s3, so perhaps it has something to do with not all the data being available at that time or something of the sort. I've gone ahead and created a [bug report](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/9764) on GitHub, but I currently don't have the means to provide a reproducible example there. If you do, would you mind posting it there?

Comment: I think that this bug is highly linked to the parquet files used and I cannot share those. But if I am able to create a reproducible example w/ dummy data, I'll provide it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discovered by aywandji in the aformentioned [github issue](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/9764#issuecomment-1355693752), the problem comes from the way dask access the min/max metatada.

It is accessed with an integer (the i*th* column) BUT this index of a column's name can change from one file to another in the same directory. (*i.e.* the filtered column is not at the same position in every file).

<s>It is [currently being patched](https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/9772) and we hope it will get inserted in the next dask release!</s>

From @filpa

> It is fixed starting with the `dask=2023.1.1` release, which was released on 2023-01-28.

Comment: For completeness' sake: the bug is fixed starting with the `dask=2023.1.1` release, which was released on 2023-01-28.

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably arises when `min` and `max` haven't been redefined before, so they still refer to the built-in functions that compute the minimum and maximum of two numbers, which obviously can't be compared with a string. Try using different name for these variables (as a rule of thumb, avoid too generic variable names which could be already defined in the standard library).

Comment: I'm not sure we're talking about the same thing. While the naming of the variables is unfortunate, they are defined in `dask` itself - not in my user code. They do not refer to the built-ins in the above stacktrace, and are set to `None`, hence the error.

Comment: I'm not sure they are defined in `dask`, I think the fields `"min"` and `"max"` are, but you know better than me. Either way, have you tried setting them to a default value (big value for `min`, small for `max`) at the beginning of your code?

Comment: Yes, they are defined in `dask`. The code snippet that is part of the stacktrace is literally part of `dask.dataframe.io.parquet.core.py:1275`, so I have no control over that part.